# How to check if a text box associated with a checkbox is checked or not in jsp?

Tags: html, jsp, servlets, checkbox

I want to put check box in every line I fetch from database.
The query is

> select Name from Projects where id<5;

Lets say there are 4 text boxes and check boxes in front of them.The user will be putting some values in the text boxes he selects.
Now how would I know which text boxes are filled by the user ?
I used the following code to generate the check boxes in JSP.

```
<form action="">
<%while(resultset.next()) { %>
 <input type="text" name="txtbx">
<input type="checkbox" name="pname"><% out.println(resultset.getString(1)); %><br>
<% } %>
</form>
```

Comment: `<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxname" value="ON">`

This will return empty string,and if it is unchecked it will return _NULL_

Comment: Are you storing the checkbox state (checked/un-checked) into the database?

Comment: No @Arvind not the checkbox state but the value in the textbox associated with it.